# p:imageCropper causes "java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid URI character encoding" only on FireFox

Tags: jsf, firefox, primefaces, glassfish, crop

I have the below image cropper:

```html
<h:form>
    <p:imageCropper id="imageDialog" 
                    value="#{petForm.croppedImage}" 
                    image="#{petForm.uploadedFilename}" 
                    maxSize="#{petForm.width},#{petForm.height}" 
                    minSize="#{petForm.width},#{petForm.height}" />
</h:form>
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and Opera. However, when I use FireFox, I get the following exception on my GlassFish 4.0 server:

```
java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid URI character encoding
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.HttpRequestURIDecoder.decode(HttpRequestURIDecoder.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.RequestURIRef.getDecodedRequestURIBC(RequestURIRef.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.RequestURIRef.getDecodedRequestURIBC(RequestURIRef.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. The cause was not visible in the information provided so far in my question. I was using backslashes `\` as image URI, basically like below:

```html
<p:imageCropper value="\resources\image.jpg" />
```

It appears that Chrome and Opera silently switch backslashes `\` to slashes `/` and get the correct resource. FireFox didn't do it and still uses backslashes when downloading the image.

After I changed the image URI like below, all worked fine.

```html
<p:imageCropper value="/resources/image.jpg" />
```